# What is the difference between [locale] and [localization]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

#### Comparison of the tag descriptions

The [localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization) tag was created on Mar 9, 2011 and the first
sentence of [its tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/localization/info) says :
*Localization is the process of adapting internationalized software
for a specific **region** or **language** by adding locale-specific
components [...]*

The [locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locale) tag was created about half a year later, on Sep 3,
2011 and [has a usage guidance (excerpt)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/locale/info)
saying in the last sentence :
*Usually a locale identifier consists of at least a **language**
identifier and a **region** identifier.*

#### Are they synonyms?

The point I want to make, is that the descriptions of both tags
mention both **region** and **language**.
To me, these tags come across as synonyms.

If agreed, which tag should be made a synonym of which?
– It really doesn't matter much, but I would put my vote on keeping
[locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locale) – simply because it's shorter than [localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization).

#### Current synonyms

The [localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization) tag already has synonyms [l10n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/l10n),
[localisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localisation), [localize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localize).

The [locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locale) tag does not (yet) have any synonyms.

#### Should I instead have *suggested* these tags to be synonymized?

I *do* have the (overall) reputation required to suggest these
changes.
However, I *don't* have the required *total answer score of 5 or more*
on either of the tags.

Should I still have made a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/locale/synonyms)?
– Rather than asking this meta question?

Comment: I might add that there are currently 5,017 questions tagged
[tag:locale] and 13,298 questions tagged [tag:localization], of which
371 questions have both tags.

Comment: I would say that the number of questions for the respective tags could
be taken as a vote to make
[`locale`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/locale/info) a synonym of
[`localization`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/localization/info),
rather than the other way around.
Provided of course that we can agree that the tags are indeed
synonyms.

Comment: "en-US" and "en-GB" are *locales*. "truck" and "lorry" are different *localisations* that rely on the locale.

Comment: @VLAZ, Do you mean *localizations*?

Answer (score 10):

'Locale' has to do with where something is, either in origin, access, or in its use. Localization has to do with issue regarding different languages - or even different variants of the same language -, cultural symbols, and UI formatting. It is certainly possible that these tags might overlap.

They are not synonyms.

Comment: Thanks for answering. There is also a [tag:local] tag.
[Description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/local/info).

Comment: I wonder if I should note that my definitions are really with respect to programming. From a very strict, but general, linguistic definition, they are much closer in meaning. Since I've come across issues in both professionally, and thus have an idea of the practical differences, that's biased my answer

Comment: OK.
My own bias is even more restrictive than with respect to programming,
I would say.
Namely that I have been reading the
[locale description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/locale/info)
and the
[localization description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/localization/info)
and compared them.
From those descriptions I have scratched my head, trying to understand
the difference – having a hard time to find any.

Comment: I have also looked at the
[revision history of the localization tag](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5241141/revisions)
and compared it with 
[the description of the locale tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/locale/info).
From that comparison, I still have a hard time seeing any essential
difference.
On the contrary, the similarities are striking, with both descriptions
mentioning both _language_ and _region_.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, here is the
[excerpt history of the locale tag](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7296341/revisions).

Comment: Well, where I've run into locale issues that had nothing to do with language has been, among other surprising things, how date/time is formatted, how menus, especially drop down menus, are presented, and how money is formatted. Localization issues I've run into are bit more obvious, translating what we've so generously presented in English, in another language where an exact translation is simply impossible, often making them especially verbose and requiring a fluent speaker (typically a local distributor) to do the actual translation, and then for us to incorporate that.

Comment: Surprised there's not a (local)currency tag of some type. Guess that's much less common an issue that's run into.

Comment: _Well, where I've run into locale issues that [...] has been, among
other surprising things, how date/time is formatted, how menus,
especially drop down menus, are presented, and how money is formatted._
– OK. But for the scenario you describe, (instead of considering
the [tag:locale] tag) I would probably consider one of the following
tags :
[tag:localdate], [tag:localdatetime], [tag:localtime],
[tag:money-format], [tag:datetime-format], [tag:number-formatting],
[tag:simpledateformat], [tag:date-format], [tag:date-formatting],
[tag:decimalformat].

Comment: My mistake: I missed the [tag:money-format].
Well, that is not _local_ of course.

Comment: Ah, there is it is.

Comment: I think you are correct, but doesn't "locale" have a very specific meaning when it comes to computers?